# SequenceFiles vs HAR's vs Files vs CombineFileInputFormat in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

What's the best way to process small files? I have been reading answers and reading and I don't find any real good way to do it. If I have 20Tb of small data in HDFS, what should I do?
If I'm going to process my data a lot of times, I would turn them into SequenceFiles, but what happen if I will only process them once?

I have read some possibilities, If there're more and someone could correct me in some of them, it'd be great.

**SequenceFiles.**

CONS: The problem is that I have to run a mapreduce, so if I only want to process the data once, I think it's not worth it. If I have to run so many mapreduce as files I have, why should I waste my time turn my files into a SequenceFile??

PROS: It saves space in the nameNode and there's a SequenceInputFormat implemented.

**Files**

CONS: So many mapreduces as files I have. It spends too many memory in the NameNode

**CombineFileInputFormat**

CONS: It spends too many memory in the NameNode

PROS: It could combile files by blocks, so I don't have to execute as many maps as files.

**HAR's**

CONS: If I want to generate, I have to execute a mapreduce job, same problem than SequenceFiles. Some point files are duplicated, so I need extra memory to generate them, after that, I could delete the old files.

PROS: We could pack files, I'm not sure if each HAR goes just one mapreduce.

What I'm looking for if a way to pack (if it's possible to compress files) and don't have to execute one mapreduce per file without executing a mapreduce to generate those "new" files, and in the same time to save memory in the NameNode.
SequenceFiles looks pretty good, but it's looks too expensive to generate them.